# How 'tightly' can accelerator pipes turn?

Tags: particle-physics, accelerator-physics

I am designing a particle accelerator for a class.  I want to know how tight of a turn an accelerator pipe can make; is there a defined maximum?  Is there a calculation that needs to be made considering the type of particle/energy of the particle/magnets available?

Comment: Have you done much reading into how particle accelerators work?

Comment: Related: https://www.popularmechanics.com/science/a23151/how-particle-acceleraters-are-designed/

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/62/why-is-the-lhc-circular-and-27km-long

Comment: The first cyclotron was 5 inches in diameter. The 11 inch cyclotron exceeded 1MeV (protons).

Comment: Low-energy accelerators (cyclotrons and synchrocyclotrons) don't even have "pipes," per se. Particles are accelerated on a spiral trajectory in a cylindrical cavity within a pair of D-shaped electrodes ("dees").

Comment: For high-energy accelerators, my answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/382145/106502) may be a start.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hint: consider the Lorentz force and the centrifugal force. Those laws (for classical mechanics) are sufficient, it probably doesn't apply for particles near the speed of light.